# Python Add-In will not run

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, arcgis-10.4

I am using ArcMap 10.4.

I’ve been trying to implement a python add-in that runs when Arcmap is opened.

When the script does run it joins a layer with a feature service layer. I have everything working if you run it in the Arcmap python window. When I take the next step and make it into an add-in it will not work. I added a sleep time to it to delay running until arc is fully open in hopes that it would fix the problem, but no such luck.

I performed a test with a text file and it will update the text file when arc is opened so I know that it is indeed running, it’s just not doing what I want it to. Any ideas?

Here is what I have:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class RoadJoin(object):
    """Implementation for RoadJoin_addin.RoadJoin (Extension)"""
    def __init__(self):
        # For performance considerations, please remove all unused methods in this class.
        self.enabled = True
    def startup(self):
        pass
        # Local variables:
Roads_2015 = "Roads 2015"
Roads_2015__2_ = Roads_2015
All_roads = "private\\transportation_FA_wa\\All roads"

time.sleep(30)
        # Process: Add Join
arcpy.AddJoin_management(Roads_2015, "BRUCE_ID", All_roads, "BRUCE_ID", "KEEP_ALL")
```

Comment: So I've removed the `time.sleep()` and fixed my indentation. I have to leave `pass` in or the script won't run in the Python window. I am still unable to get it to run on start. For a short term workaround I have made the python tool into a toolbar and for now you have to press the button when you open a new arc. It's not ideal but until I can figure this out it will have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation appears wrong and I am not sure why you have left `pass` in there.  I also think the `time.sleep()` will be unnecessary.

To get further try using:

```
class RoadJoin(object):
    """Implementation for RoadJoin_addin.RoadJoin (Extension)"""
    def __init__(self):
        # For performance considerations, please remove all unused methods in this class.
        self.enabled = True
    def startup(self):
        # Local variables:
        Roads_2015 = "Roads 2015"
        Roads_2015__2_ = Roads_2015
        All_roads = "private\\transportation_FA_wa\\All roads"

        # Process: Add Join
        arcpy.AddJoin_management(Roads_2015, "BRUCE_ID", All_roads, "BRUCE_ID", "KEEP_ALL")
```